# What is the difference between appindicator and AppIndicator3

Tags: python, application-development, indicator

Ubuntu indicators written in python can be done with two APIs : appindicator and AppIndicator3. What is the difference between them and is there any advantage to using one over the other ?

Comment: Isn't this the difference between python 2 and 3? Appindicator is for python2 while appindicator3 is for python3?

Comment: @Parto nope. Take a look at the examples provided by [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version) . They use python2 style print function, so it is python2 in either case. In addition , `#!/usr/bin/env python` by default links to python2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences might seem subtle in actual usage, but:

- [`libappindicator1` is bound via GTK2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libappindicator1)
- [`libappindicator3-1` is bound via GTK3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libappindicator3-1).

There may be deeper stuff that you can look into but that should get you pointed in the right direction. Nothing to do with the version of Python. All the heavy lifting is done through [GObject introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GObjectIntrospection).

Oh there does seem to be a difference in the version of `libindicator` each binds to too.